# How to create separate screens in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I am constantly finding myself building programs where there are multiple screens. For example, consider a program where the initial layout offers two buttons: create file or edit file. Upon clicking one, it takes the user to a new screen supporting whatever button they press. Then they click a back button and it takes them back to the main screen of the program. I am wondering how to best do separate menus like this. Would it be best just to create separate methods setting up each screen, then call the appropriate one when a button (like "back" button) is clicked? This is what I was thinking of doing, but seeing as there are many ways to do this, I want to get opinions on a possibly better way of changing the screen displayed.
Thanks, AJ

Comment: I get the feeling you do not mean "screen" as in a monitor (or: GraphicsEnvironment, GraphicsDevice).
Perhaps a little clarification of what exactly you mean by screen?

Comment: I thought that might be a little confusing, but wasn't sure how to best say it. It's like when you're in an install wizard and you click "Next" or "back" buttons, everything inside of the window changes. Each one of those separate things is what i am considering a screen. You click "next", and it takes you to the next "screen". I don't really know how else to describe it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have added an answer which I hope gets at what you want.

Comment: wondering about the down-votes: not much wrong with the question except still in the learning phase of the technical vocabulary. +1 to compensate a bit :-)

Comment: In the grand scheme of things I thought it wasn't too bad, hence why I attempted an answer, just required a little clarification. @Alex G, Don't forget to select one of the answers below if it has answered the question(s), or comment if they do not.

Comment: Done, sorry for the wait.
Just to clarify...would you call "screens" something like "menus"? I would have done that, except a menu could get confused with the "File, Edit, ..." menu at the top of most programs. Or a few other things. What would you call the "screens"?

Comment: "Screens" is definitely a reference to a multi-monitor environment. I am not sure if there is an easy word that describes what you are after, but using Class names as a description is often a lot better to get across what you mean (i.e. JPanels that sit on top of each other, and only one is visible at a time depending on a button event), rather than the terminology that I know that my parents or grandmother would use; hopefulyy you know what I mean here ;)

Comment: Whilst screen may be acceptable in certain social circles (my grandma for example), it is quite ambiguous when in a technical/development context and not talking about another monitor - though this is mostly my opinion.

Comment: Funny, usually I've only had to explain what I mean regarding "screen" to my grandma, so I understand perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your 2nd comment to the original question, I think it is best to look at using Panels.

Look at using multiple panels for each of the activities you want:

```
JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel thirdPanel = new JPanel();
```

Ensure all panels are hidden when initialised, and then simply swap a panel for another one upon a button click event using:

```
firstPanel.hide();
secondPanel.show();
```

Depending on the layout you use, there are also other techniques. For example, rather than removing and adding (or showing and hiding multiple panels), if you use BorderLayout you can simple "replace" a BorderLayout area with another panel and then revalidate:

```
container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, thirdPanel);
container.validate();
```

Note also that different Operating Systems (Windows, Mac etc) will have different styles they like to adhere to. For example you mentioned a typical Windows installer; people have come to expect an installer to look and work in a certain way, but on a different OS there are a completely different set of expectations and looks.

Further reading:

[Tutorial on using panels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)

[Java SE 7 (JPanel API)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)

---

**Edit**:

> I am wondering how to best do separate menus like this. Would it be best just to create separate methods setting up each screen, then call the appropriate one when a button (like "back" button) is clicked?

This comes down to personal preference. Do you want to initalise everything on startup and have quicker swaps between panels (or as you called them: "screens"), OR do you want a quicker inital startup and essentially have "lazy loading" of each component as and when you need it.

Personally I opt for everything during initalisation (unless there is a lot of things to do or load during your applications startup). This really comes down to personal preference.

---

Another **edit**:
Speaking about layouts, perhaps a different layout style would also help you out, something like this:

[CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Hope this helps out somewhat.

Comment: Probably the most in-depth answer I've seen. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Actions framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), it's a great way of developing common level actions for re-use

Answer (score 1):

If the state of the screen depends on the state of the previous screen (e.g. like in a wizard) you can follow the steps described in [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/)